# Should we create [log4js] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-creation-request

I would like to create a new tag for [log4js](https://github.com/nomiddlename/log4js-node).

There's already a tag for [log4javascript](http://log4javascript.org/), which is also a logger for JavaScript inspired by log4j, but log4js is a different module and deserves a different tag.

When I tried to create the tag by tagging a question with "log4js", a red box appeared, telling me that it was suspiciously similar to "log4j", and that I should ask here. Obviously, a Java logger and a JavaScript logger deserve separate tags.

Comment: Based on this search, there seems to be around a dozen existing questions for log4js:  http://stackoverflow.com/search?page=2&tab=relevance&q=log4js%20%5bjavascript%5d

Comment: Why not call it log4j-node to make it easier to tell them apart? I was halfway through your question before I realized the **s** at the end.

Comment: I just created [tag:log4js-node]. If someone creates [tag:log4js], we can create a synonym.

Comment: Also, there's [tag:log4javascript] to be used for node/non-node environments alike.

Comment: @JasonMArcher [Search with quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22log4js%22+%5Bjavascript%5D), otherwise you also get *log4j*.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  @Krumia, log4javascript is a similar logger, but it's not the same.

Comment: @lexicore That wasn't a problem, I read through nearly all the results to confirm.

Comment: Oh dear.  Apparently [log4js-node](https://github.com/nomiddlename/log4js-node) is a fork of [log4js](https://github.com/stritti/log4js) that adds support for Node.js.  This is getting confusing.

Comment: @JasonMArcher: Actually log4js-node is not a superset of log4js. log4js-node has stripped some browser specific code from log4js. So clearly they are being developed into separate directions, and should be considered different software.

Comment: Ok.  Well, the questions are now all under one tag, so they will be easy to find if log4js can get created.